# Repeating ID uses in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a following set up:

```
    <a href="#" id="A" >My Site</a>
    <a href="#" id="A" >Your Site</a>
    <a href="#" id="A" >Her site</a>
    <a href="#" id="A" >His Site</a>
    <a href="#" id="A" >Our Site</a>
```

And a button:

```
    <a href="#" id="B" >Yay</a>
```

Then following javascript:

```
 <script>                           
  jQuery("#A").click(function()
        { jQuery("#B").trigger('click');           
  return false;       });                       
 </script>
```

In this setting, when "A" is clicked, then "B" is clicked as well.

It works well for the very first button ("My Site"). However other buttons are not working as if only the first `id` was recognized by the javascript and rest are simply ignored.

I mean, I can change the `id` of other buttons and repeat the javascript, however that seems like a poorly written idea.

What would be the best way of dealing in this situation? (a clean and efficient way).

Also, let say that I do have repeating javascript with different `id` as example below (for different buttons to trigger different buttons).

```
   <script>                         
  jQuery("#A").click(function()
        { jQuery("#B").trigger('click');           
  return false;       });   

  jQuery("#C").click(function()
        { jQuery("#D").trigger('click');           
  return false;       });   

  jQuery("#E").click(function()
        { jQuery("#F").trigger('click');           
  return false;       });                       
 </script>
```

In this case, is there a way for me to condense the repeating javascripts?

Thanks!

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: So there is no clean way other than using different `id` for each individual `anchor`.

Comment: If you just want to build that structure you don't need the id property, you can build the html in code.

Comment: @steveKim Use class selector. Duplicate ID selectors will give you unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. ID must be unique. JS will take first element with that ID and will ignore rest elements. Use classes for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.A').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#B').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="A">My Site</a>
<a href="#" class="A">Your Site</a>
<a href="#" class="A">Her site</a>
<a href="#" class="A">His Site</a>
<a href="#" class="A">Our Site</a>
<hr/>
<button onClick="alert('Clicked B')" id="B">Maybe clicked</button>
```

---

If you have to make reference what element must be clicked and your links does not have any link to other page, you can use it's `href` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.A').click(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#a" class="A">My Site</a>
<a href="#b" class="A">Your Site</a>
<a href="#a" class="A">Her site</a>
<a href="#c" class="A">His Site</a>
<a href="#a" class="A">Our Site</a>
<hr/>
<button onClick="alert('Clicked A')" id="a">Maybe A clicked</button>
<button onClick="alert('Clicked B')" id="b">Maybe B clicked</button>
<button onClick="alert('Clicked C')" id="c">Maybe C clicked</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

[ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) of an element must be unique so you can use a class to group similar elements, use a `data-*` attribute to specify which element's click has to be triggered.

> A unique identifier for the element.
>  There must not be multiple
>   elements in a document that have the same id value.

```
<a href="#" class="click" data-target="a" >My Site</a>
<a href="#" class="click" data-target="b">Your Site</a>
<a href="#" class="click" data-target="c">Her site</a>
<a href="#" class="click" data-target="d">His Site</a>
<a href="#" class="click" data-target="e">Our Site</a>


<a href="#" id="a" >Yay</a>
<a href="#" id="b" >Yay</a>
<a href="#" id="c" >Yay</a>
```

then

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).click();
})
```

Comment: I see how this works. I was not familiar with `data-target`. It makes sense how to use it. Thanks Arun! =)

Comment: `data-target` looks to me the simplest and efficient way to handle this scenario.

Comment: It can be optimized: in `data-target` specify full selector, so in jQuery event you don't have to concatenate string: `<a data-target="#a"></a>`, `$($(this).data('target')).trigger('click');`

Comment: @Justinas yes... that can be done like `<a href="#" class="click" data-target="#a" >My Site</a>` then `$($(this).data('target')).click();`

Answer (score 2):

In HTML ID must be unique,You can enclose all anchors inside a block element and do like as follows

```
 <div id="A">
    <a href="#">My Site</a>
    <a href="#">Your Site</a>
    <a href="#">Her site</a>
    <a href="#">His Site</a>
    <a href="#">Our Site</a>
  </div>
```

Button

```
 <a href="#" id="B" >Yay</a>
```

Script

```
 <script>                           
 jQuery("#A a").click(function()
    { 
     jQuery("#B").trigger('click');           
     return false;      
   });                       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` of an element has to be unique. Thus, I would suggest using a class:

```
<a href="#" class="A" >My Site</a>
<a href="#" class="A" >Your Site</a>
<a href="#" class="A" >Her site</a>
<a href="#" class="A" >His Site</a>
<a href="#" class="A" >Our Site</a>
```

Then:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("A");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var ele = elements[i];
    jQuery(ele).click(function()
        { jQuery("#B").trigger('click');           
        return false;       });   
}
```

Comment: Why use JS and jQuery? Why not use class selector from jQuery?